# how can i add image effect on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add loading effect on `<div>`. In this code my `members.php` is so big file so its take time to load. So I want to show that loading… in my member `<div>` with effect. my javascript skills are so poor so I don’t know is this a right idea to do this or I have to code in `member.php`. I am so new and try to learn so please help me. I have tried with some free text javascript effect but I couldn’t find what I looking for. I want some image effect like rounding circle or something like that. Here is my code. I appreciate all answers.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#member').load('members.php').show();
 });                               
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id member>Loading…</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you simply have to find an animated gif for the loading, and when the file is loaded replace the div content with the new content

Comment: You have asked 8 questions on your account, but accepted 0 answers as being helpful.  You should take a few minutes and read [the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how this community works. This is not a forum where you ask a question and just take the answers given to you.  You would certainly have more people willing to help you if you improved your acceptance rating a bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Ajax animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938190/jquery-ajax-animation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### jQuery

```
function showLoading()
{
    $('<div class="loading"/>').appendTo('#member');
}

showLoading();

$('#member').load('members.php');
```

### CSS

```
.loading {
    background: url('') no-repeat;
    padding: 12px;
}
```

Replace the url with the path to the loading image you want, and the padding should be half the image area size.

[Simple fiddle available here](http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/rZHDC/)