# display "page loading" message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display an image (.gif) for "page loading" in html page until the output from my_script.py gets displayed, and I've no idea how to do that. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/9X4gW/) is what I've got so far. Many thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="loading">
   <p><img src="./images/loading.gif" /> Please Wait</p>
</div>

<form action="./cgi-bin/my_script.py" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="fname">
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**js:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").submit(function() {
            showLoading();
            $('#content').load('./cgi-bin/my_script.py', null, showResponse);
        });

        function showResponse() {
            hideLoading();
        }

        function showLoading() {
            $("#loading").show();
        }

        function hideLoading() {
            $("#loading").hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery?

Comment: Do you want a dialog to popup with a loading indicator, because it seems like you already have a loading indicator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script can be simplified to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').html('put your loading html here').load('/ajax_html_echo/',function(response, status, xhr) {
            //This is the callback. You can check for error here.
            //For example if (status == 'error') alertTheMedia();
        });
    });
});​
```

The revisions I made are:

- `e.preventDefault()` to prevent default form submission if user has Javascript enabled.
- Added the loading message to the `#content` selector, change the internal of `html()` to what you want to be displayed. This will cause the initial content to be your loading message, then it will either be replaced by what's returned by `.load` on success, or you'll have to explicitly tell it what to be replaced with if it's an error.
- Condensed code, easier to read, so easier to maintain.

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8pgrD/