# Help me make a jquery AJAXed divs' links work like an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to make a few divs on the same page work similar to iframes. Each will load a URL which contains links. When you click on those links I want an AJAX request to go out and replace the div's html with new html from the page of the clicked link. It will be very similar to surfing a page inside an iframe.

Here is my code to initially load the divs (this code works):

onload:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.foo.com/videos.php",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#HowToVideos").replaceWith(html);
  }
});
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.foo.com/projects.php",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#HowToProjects").replaceWith(html);
  }
});
```

This is a sample of code that I'm not quite sure how to implement but explains the concept. Could I get some help with some selectors(surround in ?'s) and or let me know what is the correct way of doing this? I also want to display a loading icon, which I need to know where the right place to place the function is.

```
$(".ajaxarea a").click(function(){
        var linksURL = this.href; // 
        var ParentingAjaxArea = $(this).closest(".ajaxarea");;
        $.ajax({
      url: linksURL,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $(ParentingAjaxArea).replaceWith(html);
      }
    });
    return false;
});

$(".ajaxarea").ajaxStart(function(){
    // show loading icon
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! The problem was I was using the function ".replacewith()" which was removing my AJAXed div(class="ajaxarea") entirely instead of replacing the content. The proper function to use here was ".html()".

Here is my working code to make an AJAXed div work like an iframe:

```
//onload to initialize the div
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.foo.com/projects.php",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $('#HowToProjects').html(html);
  }
});

$(".ajaxarea a").live('click',function(e){ // must use live instead of .click()
  e.preventDefault();
  var URL = $(this).attr('href');
  var parentFrame = $(this).closest(".ajaxarea");
  $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
      parentFrame.html(html);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to listen to click events for all anchor tags inside all elements with class `ajaxarea`, then your selector works fine:

```
$(".ajaxarea a").click(function(){ .. });
```

And this line of code, while not a selector (you're just accessing a property on the DOM element that was clicked), should work fine as well:

`var linksUrl = this.href;`

As for `ParentingAjaxArea`, you'll need to use `$(this).closest()` with a selector to determine which parent you want, but it's hard to give a specific example without knowing your HTML structure.  It looks like you want `ParentingAjaxArea` to be either the element with id `#HowToProjects` or `#HowToVideos`, so you could write:

`var ParentingAjaxArea = $(this).closest("#HowToProjects, #HowToVideos");`

As for the loading dialog, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery) explains a good method (using `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop`).

**Edit:** I also noticed you're using the `click` event--If you plan on being able to attach event handlers to links that will be inserted into the DOM via AJAX later, look at [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: thanks for the help! I also found "closest()" to be what I want to use for ParentingAjaxArea, this way the HTML structure can be anything. Is it ok to use "this" instead of "$(this)"? See above edit for example.

Comment: @Dave: You're correct, closest is better in this case, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Dave: You need to wrap `this` in a jQuery call because `this` inside an event handler just refers to the element that the handler was called on, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ajaxarea a").live('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //*
  var URL = $(this).attr('href');
  var parentFrame = $(this).parent(".ajaxarea"); //**
  $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
      parentFrame.replaceWith(html); //***
    }
  });
});
```

- * - added `preventDefault` to prevent click action (see `e` in function's arguments)
- ** - instead of `closest`, i used `parent` – like it more for it's descriptive qualities
- *** - the `var` containing parent AJAX frame *should* be jQuery object, no need to wrap it in `$(..)`

This should work fine, but beware, it's untested.

**edit**:

You *probably* need a live (okay, I'm sure you need it). what `click()` does it's that it adds to all elements at the time in DOM an `onClick` event. What `live()` does, it's that it waits for any change in DOM and runs used selector (`.ajaxarea a`) again and if it fits for any of new elements, it adds the action. In pseudocode, it does basically this:

```
DOM.hasChanged{
  $('selector').click(..)
}
```

Comment: oh, so do I need to use live() to make it work after the content has reloaded?

Comment: yes, that's another difference :) I'll edit the answer with a little clarification

Comment: for some reason $(".ajaxarea a") doesn't seem to be selecting links inside the div. If I change it to $("a") it does. But i don't want it to select all the other links.

Comment: what's the class/id of all the ajax divs? Post it as HTML in question, please.

Answer (score 0):

I used this example for my own web page:

http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp

It works quite well and uses hash tags and jQuery.history.js for the history of your browser. It works very nice, because you can let something like a media player just continue playing. Take a look at [my own site](http://andereska.nl) elsewise, where you can find the javascript file: `ajaxpages.js`. I haven't used `live()`, but maybe I should.