# Want to show "loading....." in PHP page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, zend-framework, accordion

I am developing a web-page in PHP that needs following functionality:
1. When User click on "Say Thanks" it should be changed with "Done!".
2. At the same time I want to call an action in indexController.
3. At this time I want to show "loading...." 
4. The current page has a lot of dynamic contents that should also not change.

Please suggest me what should I do to complete above tasks......

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure you need an AJAX call. I usually do that for loading comments and such when you press "more". In my case, there's an empty div and an `<a>` tag with the link to the comments view (with a separate action, ofc). Then I use jQuery for the AJAX magic:

```
$(function() { 
    $("a.CommentsListBtn").click(function() { 
        var tmpHref = $(this).attr("href");
        var tmpLayer = $(this).parent().children("div.CommentsList");
        tmpLayer.load(tmpHref, function() {
            tmpLayer.stop().slideDown("medium");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use [JQuery](http://jquery.com), [JQuery UI](http://ui.jquery.com). It isn't that hard! What I think you need to learn is the following for your problem:

- [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)