# How to display a waiting image on page load in asp net

Tags: asp.net, image, wait, pageload

I want to show a waiting image/progress bar on page load event. In page load event, some code is being processed for displaying a report which takes 1/2 minutes to display on the aspx page, meanwhile the aspx is being empty and nothing is displyed, this is not so userfriendly. So, I want to show an image indicating page is being processed. 
I tried searching in google and found some code samples but couldnt achieve my target. How to implement this. 
Requirement is nothing but: Display an image/progress bar until the report is processed.

Any help in this :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you checked this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Ajax and AjaxProgressBar. In the AjaxProgressbar you can give your custom images to give your processing message.

Have i misunderstood your question?