# jquery how to show wait message during page load

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, displaytag

Being new to JQuery I have been hunting around to see how I can show a wait image to the user upon the loading of a page.

the page is simple, user lands on the page, and selects several values and then selects a submit button.

Submits the request to the back end and then the results are returned and then displayed.  I am able to show a wait image upon the select button, but when the page is rendering the results using displaytag there is no image.

I tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h3><img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" /> We are loading your request.  Please be patient.</h3>' });
  });

  $(window).load(function() {
    $.unblockUI();
  });  

</script>
```

But that did not seem to work.  The image and message show up at the very end not during the rendering of the page.

Using IE if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your sending an ajax request to the server? If so, you can utilize jQuery's `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` methods as described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery).

Comment: I am using DWR as the AJAX engine.

Answer (score 0):

Using css:

```
#pageLoading { 
width:100%;
height: 100%;
background: black;
position:absolute;
z-index: 1000;
top: 0px;
left:0px;
}
```

You could create a 'mask' with your loading gif inside of it. Then use your jquery to fadeOut() the div when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){}) is called after the page is loaded / rendered. Go with superUntitled answer, use CSS and then fade it out after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have another way is the [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation), specificly the dialog widget for displaying a `.gif` picture with the `modal: true` option for blocking the interface . Then if the process finished you can simply destroy the dialog using `$( this ).dialog( "close" )` method