# Load when page loads, not on click, etc(ajax,php)

Tags: php, ajax, selector

```
$(function(){  
    $('p.load_it a').click(function(){  
        $('#demo_content').load('http://d.com/myphp.php?  nice=1149632');  
        return false;  
    });  
});
```

Click me to load some HTML with AJAX.

```
    <div id='demo_content'> 

    </div>
```

I wanted to know if anyone can give me advice as to how I can load this kind of Effect not by a click, but by an animated "loading" effect.

Let me know if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the JavaScript code to be executed when the page loads?

Comment: Yes, after my image and other text has loaded, I want this content to load automatically- and i will be adding a animation loading type spinner(i saw them on ajaxinfo.net, or something like that, its on here somewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will execute your `load()` call when the DOM on the page is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo_content').load('http://example.com/myphp.php? nice=1149632');
    return false;
});
```

<del>As for your 'loading' request, I suggest you take a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery).</del> Nevermind, I just saw you already had something in mind.

Comment: I proceeded to insert that as followed:    $(function(){  
  $('p.load_it a').click(function(){       $(document).ready(function() {             
   $('#demo_content').load('http://vbizmarketing.com/myphp.php?  nice=1149632');  
   return false;  
    
  });  
 })    But It did not work

Comment: Once you nest it inside a `$.click()`, it'll only fire once that selector is clicked. Copy it as I wrote it.

Comment: Sounds Good-I will replace my current script with your suggested script, and will see what happens-And that stil did not work as planned--

Comment: What does your code look like now and what do you want this code to do *exactly*?

Comment: <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo_content').load('http://vbizmarketing.com/myphp.php? nice=1149632');
    return false;
})
</script>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="logo">/div>
<div id="pic"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<p class='load_it'><a href="#">Load</a></p> 
  <div id='demo_content'> 
  
  </div>
</body>
</html> I am doing a mock up of what my full page will look like, right now I just need to get the data displayed/pulled correctly

Comment: @esqew I want to Load the data that I am requesting via ajax, and basically have a loading bar/progress  bar that will display as ajax is  automatically pulling the data from the xml  into the div.

Comment: Make sure your request parameters are free of typos (address doesn't have `http://` and has an extraneous space in there). You're also missing a semicolon after your closing bracket and parenthesis. Check your browser's JavaScript console for more information on errors and warnings in your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://example.com/myphp.php?nice=1149632',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#demo_content').html(data);
      }
    beforeSend: function(){
        //show loading here
        $('#demo_content').html("Loading...");
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the javascript code to be executed when the page has been loaded, you can also add the script at the bottom of the page, like this:

```
<script>
$('#demo_content').load('http://example.com/myphp.php? nice=1149632');
</script>
```