# Show loading indicator with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div>` with an image slider in an `<li>`. There are 12 images, and it takes some time to load all of them. While the images load, I want to show a loading GIF image. How can I do this with jQuery? My code is:

```
<div id="banner_slider">
<ul id="portfolio">                 

        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="gallery/2010/2010slider//01_quddus_helal.jpg" alt="Slider Image" border="0" /></a><br />
            <p class="caption"> Quddus Helal :: 01st - 2010</p>
        </li>               


        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="gallery/2010/2010slider//02_md_moniruzzaman.jpg" alt="Slider Image" border="0" /></a><br />
            <p class="caption"> Md Moniruzzaman :: 02nd - 2010</p>

        </li>               

   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: images in ul li are coming from ajax???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind a listener to the load event of each image.  Use a counter or some other mechanism to keep track of how many images are loaded each time the listener is invoked.  Then hide the loading indicator after the last image is loaded.  For example:

**HTML**

```
<span id="loading" style="display:none">Loading...</span>
<div class="images">
    <img class="large-image" src="http://astritademi.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/happy_panda.jpg" width="893" height="548" />
    <img class="large-image" src="http://www.pandafix.com/pandafix/images/r3387761054.jpg" width="275" height="199" />
    <img class="large-image" src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/149/357563212_f8b89ac6d8.jpg" width="500" height="375" />
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var images = $('.large-image')
      , total = images.length
      , count = 0;

    $('#loading').show();
    images.load(function() {
        count = count + 1;
        if (count >= total) {
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

You can see this example in action on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hallettj/ZefaM/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. It will run the code once the image has loaded. So if you have a gif shown, once the image has loaded, it will hide it.

**Javascript**

```
$('img#id').load(function(){
    $('#loadingGif').hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="loadingGif">
    <img src="loading.gif" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:
http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/

Answer (score 1):

if u loading all images via AJAX then use below way

### HTML

```
<div id="loadingDiv"><img src="loading.gif"></div>
```

### jQuery

```
$('#loadingDiv')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;
```

Comment: Reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery