# jQuery Ajax CGI: load script

Tags: jquery, ajax, cgi

I am trying to load my Perl CGI script's content into the HTML page. `.load()` does not work. Please tell me what's wrong here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var nom = $(this).attr("value");
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      alert('okok');
      $('body').load("../cgi-bin/essai.pl");
    } else {
      //$("#" + nom).remove();
    }
  });
```

I would like:

- When I check the checkbox (which has as value "toto") load (in Ajax) essai.pl?param=toto
- When I uncheck this checkbox, remove the content loaded before.

Hope someone has a little time to help me to leave this jQuery nightmare.
Bye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading your script's output directly into the body, hence you make all previous body content (including your checkbox(es)) disappear. I assume that is what you experience.

What you should do is have a dedicated block for the script generated content, and use that block as the target of your load function.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="controller">
  <input type="checkbox" name="toto" id="toto"></input> Load / unload content
  </div>
<div id="target">
  Content comes here
  </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
      var target_url = "../cgi-bin/essai.pl?param="+$(this).attr('name');
      $('div#target').load(target_url);
    }
    else {
      $("div#target").html('');
    }
});
```

I would also refrain from the "../cgi-bin/" type relative path definition and use absolute path instead.

Working example available at http://jsbin.com/izuni4/19

**EDIT** Seems like I didn't fully grasp what you were trying to achieve.
Here is an edited version of the same javascript which appends/removes content blocks triggered by multiple checkboxes. Hope that solves your issue:

http://jsbin.com/izuni4/22/

Comment: Great, that's what I search for. But I have 4 checkbox, when I check the first checkbox, new div load in #target, but nothing append when I check the second one. Is it because load is not like append ? It can't add more, it erase ?

Comment: @eouti: Edited answer to better fit your needs.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/izuni4/22/ is exactly what I need !! \n\n           I vote for you dude

Comment: @András Szepesházi : Are you master in Jquery and JS in general ? Because my script take several seconds to load, I would like to display a loading gif or something like that while it's executing perl code on the server.

Comment: @eouti: lol. Me no Jedi. But check this thread for ajax loading indicator solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery

Comment: @András Szepesházi : Ok thanks. I have a last question. When I load my perl content via ajax, the jquery tooltip plugin does not work on the new ajax content added. How can I apply my plugin to the new ajax content ?