# Replace page loading with Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show loading spinner in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery)

In the below screenshot till the required content is loaded it displays an image that represents loading. I saw this even while loading web pages first it displays the page loading image and at once the loading image turns to page. How this can be implemented?
[image]

Comment: This is about the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#loader_with_image").show();
});

$.ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("#loader_with_image").hide();
});
```

Comment: Well is `#loader_with_image` the DIV layer that consists of image or some other?

Comment: @Kars: yes, div with loading image

Comment: How should I declare this in HTML page? should I use `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag or any other?

Comment: @Kars: yes. after including jquery and #loader_with_image