# JQ Mobile Progress bar while posting

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

So my app does an ajax post to an external server. While this is happen I would like to display a loading dialog. More preferable I would like show a little progress bar.

Could someone point me in a good direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's is the gotcha for progress bar, your progress bar is going to be completely unaware of when the post is going to complete, you will have setup a predefined value of how long it would take. The downside to that is that its possible that you post might take longer and your progress bar might display as complete and confuse the user. Another alternative is to not completely fill the progress bar and leave it 90% full until the post actually completes and once it completes fill the progress bar to 100%. The cool thing about the spinner is that its always spinning and the users at least knows that something is still going on.

Here some documentation for the [progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) and here is a stackoverflow answer for the [spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery).

Comment: For a POST which uploads a lot of data you can rely on progress events to update the progress bar. You linked to the docs for progress bar for jQuery UI "desktop".