# Ajax request gif

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have seen that an animated loading gif loads when a an ajax request is being processed. I was wondering how this was done.

For example, there are a lot of images that are loaded from `css` file. Can I make a loading gif appear until these images are loaded.

Comment: Maybe this: http://algytaylor.blogspot.com/2011/11/tgvjs-javascript-to-reduce-page-loading.html

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean smth. like this:
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

or this: [How to show loading spinner in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you are using ASP.NET MVC?
If that is the case you can use an `@Ajax.ActionLink` and put your loading gif in an img tag specifying the id in your actionlink's AjaxOptions in the  LoadingElementId.
It would look somehow like this

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("MyAction", "MyController", new AjaxOptions(){LoadingElementId = "MyGif"})
```

It will then hide the img gif until the actionlink is triggered. Sometimes you will need to hide it yourself using css, but as far as I remember that is not the case when you are just using an img tag

Answer (score 0):

You don't really mean Ajax. The images declared in css are loaded by the browser normally.

You need the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event, try this:

1 -  Create an element with id `yourDivIdWithLoadingElement` in your html page which will be shown until all images has been loaded

```
<div id="yourDivIdWithLoadingElement:>Loading content...</div>
```

2 - Add this script in your header:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#yourDivIdWithLoadingElement').hide();
});
```

Comment: what does $(window) refer to? is it the whole html page?