# How can you stop user input actions while an AJAX query in requesting data?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a `JQUERY` function that uses `AJAX` via a `PHP` page, when the AJAX is running I have a loading.gif show for the user. When the `AJAX` returns the json data that was requested all is fine. What I would like to do would be to make any user input null while this is happening.

What would be the best way to go about this?

EDIT:

I ended up using...

```
$('#loadingDiv')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;
```

From the post [How to show loading spinner in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery)

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: You can disable input fields by adding the `disabled="disabled"` attribute

Comment: True, what about the keyboard. Could it be disabled at all?

Comment: What? No! You can't disable a user's keyboard from javascript. can you imagine the chaos?

Comment: I see your point. I'm working on an internal use system for Chrome. So it would only need to work on chrome anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Gray the screen with a spinner until the request succeed (the loading.gif)
- Disable the input field by setting `disabled=disabled`

See this question:[How to show loading spinner in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery) and [jQuery .ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, thats what I went with.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an interesting idea.

This is somewhat a dirty hack but you can disable any keyboard input within your website during Ajax requests by adding this event to `$(document).ready`:

```
​$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    return $.active == 0;
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

It works like that: `$.active` returns the number of active Ajax requests. If it is `0` then any *keydown* will be returned as `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the fields as said by xbonez. Make sure to give your users a feedback about what is keeping them from entering data. Otherwise they will think your app just freezed.