# How to show progress of jquery load

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, progress-bar

I need something similar to this ->

[How to show loading spinner in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery)
since I also call the div content with jQuery .load() function.

But instead of showing picture, I would like to show progress bar. So I need to watch progress of that request.

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you gave uses only ajaxStart and ajaxReady, not any progress.
As far as I know there is no way to determe the progress of the call via jQuery.

Comment: Yes I know there is no progress, that's why I asked if it is possible. Well than the picture has to be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Hiya **DEMO** <strike>http://jsfiddle.net/5ZRfY/</strike> ==> http://jsfiddle.net/je5qchss/

something like this perhaps. **and** please see here: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ **or** http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/ **and** http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (have some good reads)

You can always put the call on start and stop when ajax finished successfully!

**Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#progressBar').append('<div id="bar"></div>');

    // percentage of completion
    var progress = '100%';

    // Animate the #bar div
    $('#bar').animate({
        width: progress
    }, 400);

});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='progressBar'></div>​
```

**css**

```
body{
    background:#f6f6f6;    
}

/*Styling of progress bar container*/
#progressBar{
    width:300px;/*It is important to define the width of the progress bar*/
    height:40px;
    padding:0px;
    background:#ccc;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #888;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #888;
}
/*styling the progress bar*/

#bar{
    background:#499aed;
    height:100%; 
    width:0; /*sets the bar to 0*/   
}​
```

Comment: this progress bar moves always 0.4 sec and shows nothing about real load