# How to generate a waiting popup using jQuery

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile

I came across many sites for this but i did not get any ideas.

Anyone able to explain step by step... for **generating a waiting pop up** using jQuery in Android.

**i would like a pop up when loading contacts ...**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check with this

```
 function ShowPopup_click() {       
        $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
        $.mobile.loadingMessage = "Loading...";
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    }

 function HidePopup_click(){
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    }
```

Ref: http://jsfiddle.net/7fxQf/25/

Comment: Please include a description of the steps required here in this post, or it risks being deleted as ["Not an Answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'.