# Spinning Cursor while AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, ajax

I have a WebGrid in a lot of my pages that list products. And I have the following code that adds the item to the database that the user clicked on:

```
        public bool ToCart(int userId,
            string partNumber,
            string productDescription,
            int units,
            int boxes,
            decimal unitPrice,
            decimal boxPrice,
            decimal lineTotal,
            string orderId,
            DateTime dateTime,
            bool isBoxed)
        {
            bool addedToCart = false;

            try
            {
                Cart cart = new Cart()
                {
                    UserId = userId,
                    PartNumber = partNumber,
                    Description = productDescription,
                    Units = units,
                    Boxes = boxes,
                    UnitPrice = unitPrice,
                    BoxPrice = boxPrice,
                    LineTotal = lineTotal,
                    OrderId = orderId,
                    OrderDate = dateTime,
                    IsBoxed = isBoxed
                };

                database.AddToCarts(cart);
                database.SaveChanges();

                addedToCart = true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                addedToCart = false;
                Console.Write(exception.Message);
            }

            return addedToCart;
        }
```

The call to this method, looks like:

```
ToCart(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, PartNumber, ProductDescription, Units, Boxes, UnitPrice, BoxPrice, LineTotal, OrderId, DateTime.Now, IsBoxed)
```

---

Now I want to make this into an AJAX post. But I don't want anything fancy. I would just like to have the normal WaitCursor or BusyCursor show up while this is being added to the cart, and to display a `<p>item added to cart</p>` at the top of the page, when it has been added to the cart.

[image]

How can I accomplish this when a user clicks on an item they wish to add to their cart?

Comment: this post might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) plugin for that:

```
$('.addToCart').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
       before: function(){$('body').block()} ,//will be called before the ajax call begins
       complete: function(){$('body').unblock()}, //will be called when ajax completes, whether with error or success
       //on success, append message to top
       success: function(){
              var message = "<p>item added to cart</p>";
              $(message).appendTo('.topDiv');
    }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @ftom2 - I didn't think to block the UI (which I should have, since I come from Windows Forms and have done it a lot) - I'm going to give this a whirl now

Comment: May I ask, how would I 'execute' this ajax request when the user clicks on the link (of the item they want added to the cart)? Should I wrap the whole ajax code inside a named function, and call that function from within `<a onclick="functionToCall()">some link</a>`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div` (in my example below I gave mine an `id` of *loadingdiv*) containing anything you like (usually an animated GIF - look at http://ajaxload.info). Then, using jQuery, you can do this:

```
<div id="loadingdiv"><img src="spinning-image.gif" /></div>

$("#loadingdiv").
    hide().
    ajaxStart(function() { $(this).show(); }).
    ajaxStop(function() { $(this).hide(); });
```

or if you just want to change the cursor do this:

```
$(document).
    ajaxStart(function() { $(document).css("cursor", "wait"); }).
    ajaxStop(function() { $(document).css("cursor", "default"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your code add:

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

and create method that You want to call with AJAX, add WebMethod attribute to the method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string CallAJAX(string Iwant)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Iwant)) throw new Exception("What You want ?");
        return "One " + Iwant + " for You";
    }
```

Thats all the C# part.
Now to call it from Your page add script manager to the page form:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

Add JavaScript methods:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function CallAJAX() {
        var Iwant = 'ice cream';
        PageMethods.CallAJAX(Iwant, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
        //set wait cursor
        jQuery("body").css("cursor", "progress");
    }

    function OnSucceeded(result) {
        alert(result);
        //set cursor to normal
        jQuery("body").css("cursor", "auto");
    }

    function OnFailed(error) {
        alert(error.get_message());
        //set cursor to normal
        jQuery("body").css("cursor", "auto");
    }

</script>
```

With PageMethods.CallAJAX(Iwant, OnSucceeded, OnFailed); You call server C# method and attach response events.
Then You can use it with ASP.NET button for example:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="ajax call" OnClientClick="CallAJAX(); return false;" />
```