# Set an image in UI

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, image

Im using .net c# MVC3 Model. I need to show a gif called loading when I click save on the page. I used `<img src="sourcepath" alt="loading" style="display:none"/>` and trying to display it whenever user clicks save button using jquery. I have stored the image temporarily in views folder. Unfortunately, i could not see image on the screen. I can see its division with a small red cross cancel button.

Pls Help

Comment: You have to add an url to the image in the attribute src, that's why you get an red cross.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're seeing the broken image icon, it means your src "sourcepath" is wrong. You would normally put static content in the Content folder of your site, and access it using `/Content/imagename.jpg` or `/Content/Images/imagename.jpg` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the search, here you can find an solution the show an spinner when doing ajax requests:

[How to show loading spinner in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery)