# Use spinner while div loads into DOM

Tags: jquery, jstree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show loading spinner in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery)

I have a `div` that has a lot of stuff in it, and doesn't load into the DOM smoothly. Is there a way I could add a spinner kind of like you see in AJAX calls? Here is my current code.

```
<h4>Network Printers</h4>
<div id="demo1" class="demo">
    <ul class="printer-tree">
        <li>Many List Items</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="spinner" style="display:none;"></div>
```

```js
$(function () {
    $("#demo1").jstree({ 
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "checkbox", "sort", "ui" ]
    });
});
```

Comment: not a duplicate, that is for aJax.

Answer (score 2):

according to the documentation, you can bind an event to the tree creation, like this:

```
$(function () {

    $("div.spinner").show();

    $("#demo1").bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
        // tree has been loaded
        $("div.spinner").hide();
    }).jstree(
        { 
            "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "checkbox", "sort", "ui" ]
        }
    );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can!

First, your syntax seem to be invalid. The opening tag of your div doesn't gets closed; You are missing a `>`.

You could enable the spinner on default, and disable it whenever the content is loaded using a callback. I'm don't know anything about `jstree` but according to it's [documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core) you can set a callback in some methods.

Comment: I'm not seeing any missing ">"

Comment: @MattCharlton it did before. I guess someone has edited it.