# loader in ajax form jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

I am new in jQuery ajax. I have created a ajax form in magento. and it works fine. But now i want to add the loader image in that. My code for the form is written

```
jQuery(function () {
  var checkurl = URL + "customer/account/signupformpopup/";
  jQuery('#alogin').click(function () {

    jQuery('.cc-register-form').hide(600);
    jQuery('.cc-signup-form').show("slow");
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: checkurl,
      success: function (data) {
        var $signupForm = jQuery('<div class="cc-signup-form">'+data+'</div>');
        if (jQuery('#tinybox-wrap').children().hasClass('cc-signup-form')) {
          return false;
        }
        else {
          jQuery('#tinybox-wrap').append($signupForm);
        }
      }
    })

  });
});
```

Comment: similar question [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in many ways.My preferred way is to attach a function to the ajaxStart/Stop events on the element itself.

```
$('#loadingDiv')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;
```

The ajaxStart/Stop functions will fire whenever you do any ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically you need to put your loader on top of `ajax post element`, using some kind of absolute positioning or w/e else you can do. An example of that is following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9qVP/1/).
(You can click on a button and after click on a loader to make button apear again).

What you do on ajax request is hide control element and show loader, in `success` and of course `error` function handlers you show control element and hide loader. That's it, so simple :)