# Show loading spinner image in jQuery UI modal box while loading external page

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I have this modal window:

HTML:

```
<div id="showEvents"><canvas id="event" width="32" height="32"></canvas></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var dialog1 = $('<div>').dialog({ autoOpen: false,modal:true,
     height: 400,
     width: 450
    });
    $('#showEvents').click(function () {
        dialog1.load('../Lists/Event.aspx').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

now I want to show a spinner while loading. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery) question but I don't know where should I put my spinner image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `.html()`:

```
dialog1.dialog('open');
dialog1.load('../Lists/Event.aspx').html('<img src="../img/pLoader.gif"  alt="loading..."/> ');
```