# jquery loading spinner or loading message while JS running

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to show a loading spinner while my javascript is running?

I want toshow something to the user while the page is waiting.....

This is taking about 5-6 secs..so I want to show a spinner or box while its waiting

```
$.each(ARRAY, function(key, item){
                            //IM DOING SOME LOGIC HERE
                        });
```

Comment: See if this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery

Comment: Totally depends on what you are waiting for..  It looks like you are running some scripts.. which will freeze your browser until the completion of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden loading image in your page, display it when you start you function and hide it again when the function completes.

```
<img src="loading image " id="loading">


function(){
  $("#loading").show();
  your logic
  $("#loading").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just the first thing that came to mind. Probably not the best solution. But it does the job.. You could define a loading div and hide it by default. Then, while the each is doing its thing, show the loading div. So something like:

CSS:

```
   .hidden{display:none;}
```

HTML:

```
      <div class="loading hidden"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
           function(){
               $('.loading').removeClass('hidden'); 
               $.each(ARRAY, function(key, item){

                    });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Works for me with a bootstrap 5.2 spinner, with the following referenced in the html:

- bootstrap 5.2 stylesheet
- referencing the bootstrap bundle script
- jquery script

```js
$function doLogic() {
    $("#loadingImg").css('visibility','visible');

    setTimeout(function() { // allow spinner to load before work starts
    
            // logic here to load page
            
    $("#loadingImg").hide();
    },5000); //5000ms = 5secs
    }
```

```css
#loadingImg {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    align-self: center;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="spinnerContainer">
  <div id="loadingImg" class="spinner-border" role="status">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This may be helpful for AJAX logic:

```
<img id="loadingImg" src="loding.gif"/>

$('#loadingImg')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;
```

The ajaxStart/ajaxStop functions will fire whenever you do any AJAX calls and displays the loading spinner.

Alternatively, this may be helpful too:

```
function doLogic() {
    $('#loadingImg').show();

    setTimeout(function() { // allow spinner to load before work starts
        // logic here
    },500);

    $('#loadingImg').hide();
}
```

Comment: totally useless, if you do this, it just hides the img instantly

Comment: @Barbz_YHOOL that's what it is meant to do :/