# Calling a function until jQuery .post finishes loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a little new to jQuery framework and while using AJAX with normal javascript I used `readyState()` function to display a loading gif image. But, I don't know how to use that in jQuery `.post()` method. Was it possible to add a class until it finishes loading? If so, please give a code sample. My function is similar to this:

```
$.post("verify.php",{
username: u,
password: p
},function(r) {
   if(r == 1) {
     $(".elmt").addClass("loading");
   } else if (r == 0) {
     location.href = 'http://localhost';
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always prefer using `$.ajax` for things like this as it has more options than the shortcuts :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : 'verify.php',
    data: {
           username: u,
           password: p
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        $(".elmt").addClass("loading"); // add loader
    }
}).always(function() { // always executed

    $(".elmt").removeClass("loading"); // remove loader

}).done(function(r) { // executed only if successful
    if (r == 0) {
        location.href = '/';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call the `addClass` before the `$.post()` and be done with it

```
$(".elmt").addClass("loading");
$.post("verify.php", {
    username: u,
    password: p
}, function (r) {
    location.href = 'http://localhost';
});
```

Comment: @Gowtham yes... but if you want to show the loading message for all ajax requests from every part of the code then see tea2code's answer

Answer (score 2):

You could fire a custom event before starting your AJAX request.
Then in your success function, fire another to stop.

Or if you just want the loading animation:

```
$(".elmt").addClass("loading");

$.post("verify.php",{
username: u,
password: p
},function(r) {       
     $(".elmt").removeClass("loading");
     // etc...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a global way to do this using ajaxStart() and ajaxStop(). See [How to show loading spinner in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do for all your requests. You could try:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
   $(".elmt").addClass("loading");
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
  $(".elmt").removeClass("loading");
});
```

But it's not so cool to always display the loading when the request takes little time as it will cause the screen flicking. Try:

```
var timer;
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
       timer = setTimeout(function(){
          $(".elmt").addClass("loading");
       },1500);
    });

    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      $(".elmt").removeClass("loading");
    });
```

By adding a timer, only requests that take longer than 1.5 seconds ***should be considered long*** and display a loading icon.

Answer (score 0):

As you see on code below you can do your work on different results of post method

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.post("example.php", function() {
alert("success");
})
.done(function() { alert("second success"); })
.fail(function() { alert("error"); })
.always(function() { alert("finished"); });
// perform other work here ...
// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function(){ alert("second finished"); });
```