# jquery ajax page load how?

Tags: ajax, jquery

i tried many code but not successfull yet. mainly i am looking jquery ajax load page. its very simple but i can't figure out prople. see bellow sample html code. how i want.

```
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="page1">page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2"  id="page2">page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3"  id="page3">page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4"  id="page4">page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-5"  id="page5">page 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>


 <div class="contentarea" id="response">

        </div>
```

bellow is js code i tried many other also no work properly....

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // load index page when the page loads
    $("#response").load("page1.html");
    $("#page1").click(function(){
    // load home page on click
        $("#response").load("page1.html");
    });
    $("#page2").click(function(){
    // load about page on click
        $("#response").load("page2.html");
    });
    $("#page3").click(function(){
    // load contact form onclick
        $("#response").load("page3.html");
    });
});

</script>
```

if you guys know any good solution for that type loading page. please share with me.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken your code and tidied it up a bit, and switched the .load() out for .html() for testing in a jsFiddle. The code is working as you'll see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Routh/cqJ6Q/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // load index page when the page loads
    $("#response").html("DEFAULT");
    $("#page1").click(function () {
        // load home page on click
        $("#response").html("TESTING 1");
    });
    $("#page2").click(function () {
        // load about page on click
        $("#response").html("TESTING 2");
    });
    $("#page3").click(function () {
        // load contact form onclick
        $("#response").html("TESTING 3");
    });
    $("#page4").click(function () {
        // load contact form onclick
        $("#response").html("TESTING 4");
    });
    $("#page5").click(function () {
        // load contact form onclick
        $("#response").html("TESTING 5");
    });
});
```

The output changes with every button press. The only reason I can see that it's not working for you is that the HTML files aren't referenced properly.

Do you have any console output?

**UPDATED**

Here is the jsFiddle modified to have the content fade in rather than just loading:

http://jsfiddle.net/Routh/cqJ6Q/1/

I changed this:

```
$("#response").html("TESTING 1");
```

To this:

```
$("#response").hide().html("<h1>Page 1</h1><p>Page 1 has been loaded</p>").fadeIn('slow');
```

There are many more effects and combinations of tricks you can use, but that is outside the scope of this Q&A forum. Please check http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/ for more functions.

Comment: thanks thanks ... its work.. actually my code also worked.. i never tried before in localhost.. when i tried it work also... so both code work... so any idea how could e add loading animation and fade or slide effect

Comment: Since you are feeding in templates to these tab views, I might add that you should look at [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/), [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and [TextJS](https://github.com/requirejs/text) for preloading and processing your templates for these tabs.

I will update my example for fadeIn as an example for animation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, while making sure that the path of the `html` files are accurate -

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="page1" title="page1">page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2"  id="page2" title="page2">page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3"  id="page3" title="page3">page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4"  id="page4" title="page4">page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-5"  id="page5" title="page5">page 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
 <div class="contentarea" id="response">
 </div> 


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".menu a").click(function(){
        var title = this.title;
        var responseDiv = $("#response");
        $(responseDiv).empty().load(title + ".html", function(response, status, xhr){
            // function to call after the load.
            if (status == "error") {
                // Error occured
            }
            else {
                // Success
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#page1").click(function(){
    // load home page on click
        $("#response").html($('body').load("page1.html"));
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks ... its work.. actually my code also worked.. i never tried before in localhost.. when i tried it work also... so both code work... so any idea how could e add loading animation and fade or slide effect

Comment: for sliding effect or animation you can show an image in beforesend and close in success of the ajax call.

Comment: have any exmple for that ? actually i am new jquery and ajax so i don't know much yet. just want to add loading animation (gif file) and fade effect

Comment: $('#loadingDiv')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery

Comment: @AccoreLTD there are 5 types of ajax call.http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Check here: you can do any animation in before send and complete.
http://www.bennadel.com/resources/presentations/jquery/demo21/
http://spyrestudios.com/jquery-part-two-selectors-animation-and-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

This way, you can do it. I'm using it in www.sambook.ir on flag icons.

```
$('li a').click(function(){
            var address = $(this).attr('href')+ " #id(every section you want. be careful about the space before numbersign#)";
            $("#previews").empty("#response");
            $("#previews").load(address);
    });
```