# How to implement a jQuery spinner image in an AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have an jQuery AJAX request which I want to have display an ajax spinner gif while the request loads and then disappear once the request is successful, can anyone suggest the best method to implement this into my jquery code below:

```
function updateCart( qty, rowid ){
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/cart/ajax_update_item",
        data: { rowid: rowid, qty: qty },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){                
            render_cart(data);
        }           
    });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show loading spinner in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. Get a loader gif from [**ajax loader**](http://ajaxload.info) (GIF images)
2. Place this image where you want to show/hide.
3. Before the ajax, *show this image*.
4. Once completed, *hide the image*

---

```
function updateCart( qty, rowid ){
$('.loaderImage').show();
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/cart/ajax_update_item",
        data: { rowid: rowid, qty: qty },
        dataType: 'json',                         
        success: function(data){                
            render_cart(data);
            $('.loaderImage').hide();
        },
        error: function (response) {
           //Handle error
           $("#progressBar").hide();

    }           
    });
}
```

Comment: how do you mean async = false? should i change anything in the code?

Comment: You should actually hide the loading image when the success function is called, don't you reckon? p/s: `async: false` is a bad idea unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: **Never use `async: false`**. Aside from being deprecated in the latest version of jQuery, it is not the way to solve the problem. Put the `hide()` in the callback function.

Comment: Whats the reason for the error() in the ajax (sorry for if my query sounds silly)

Comment: @Zabs what happens if your ajax fails?  So you should be handling it so that it should not break other functionality.

Comment: I see what you mean thats a good point :) thanks really appreciate your efforts

Comment: Another loader image option is FontAwesome, especially if you are already using it in your project. Check out their animated icons here: http://fontawesome.io/examples/#animated.

Comment: Instead of using this `$('.loaderImage').show();` before the ajax call, you can use `beforeSend: function(){$('.loaderImage').show();}` inside the ajax call.

Answer (score 8):

```
var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    $loading.show();
  })
  .ajaxStop(function () {
    $loading.hide();
  });
```

where '#loadingDiv' is the spinner gif covering the part of the page or the complete page.

Comment: where is spinner gif?

Answer (score 5):

I do it showing/hiding a div with gif image. It works like a charm:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#progressBar").corner();  
    $("#progressBar").show();


    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "../Nexxus/DriveController.aspx",
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        //data: param,
        success: function (response) {
            //Manage your response.

            //Finished processing, hide the Progress!
            $("#progressBar").hide();
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
            $("#progressBar").hide();

        }
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: additionally you can use javascript Images to make the sure the image is showing up immediately.

Answer (score -1):

On [Preloaders.net](https://preloaders.net/en/ajax_loader_script) you can find a very open code along with all the explanations both in pure JavaScript and JQuery formats. You can get the loader images there too