# How to add loading indicator while data is loading

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to display loading indicator while data is loading. below is my current codes:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "URL",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     success: function(html) {
         $("#div").html(html);
     }
});
```

What should I do?

Comment: Hint: Add/Show it before calling `$.ajax(...)` and hide/remove it on `success()` and `error()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a jQuery spinner image in an AJAX request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445639/how-to-implement-a-jquery-spinner-image-in-an-ajax-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "URL",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     success: function(html) {
         $(selector).html();
         $("#div").html(html);
     },
     beforeSend: function(){
         $(selector).html("your loading image");
     }

});
$(selector).html();
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use jquery [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) utilities for this.

like

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( "#loading" ).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "URL",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     success: function(html) {
         $("#div").html(html);
     }
});

$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $("#loading" ).show();
});

$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  $("#loading" ).hide();
});


});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      beforeSend : function(){ $('#somediv').show();},
     url: "URL",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     success: function(html) {
      $("#div").html(html);
      $("#somediv").hide();
     }
});
```

Comment: This will give the error at line: `beforeSend : $('#somediv').show();`  there should be comma not semicolumn.

Comment: It should be `beforeSend : function(){ $('#somediv').show();},` instead of `beforeSend : $('#somediv').show();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple logic.

1) Before the ajax call, show the loading gif image.

2) on callback, hide the loading image.

```
$("#loading" ).show();
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "URL",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     success: function(html) {
         $("#div").html(html);
         $("#loading" ).hide();
     }
     error: function (html) {
         console.log("errorResponse: " + html);
         $("#loading" ).hide();
     }
});
```