# Displaying working text to user while the Jquery function is working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a Jquery function that transfers files from one location to another. Sometimes due to the size of the file, the function takes a long time and I have no way of telling the user that it is still working. 
How do I put something on the screen until the function finishes so that the user knows that the system is still working and won't refresh or close the page?

```
 function transferfile(sourceurl, desturl)
  {
   //do the transfer

   }

  $.when( transferfile() ).done(function() {
   alert("completed");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

A spinner is what you need. I found a similar thread. Have a look at the solution here
[How to implement a jQuery spinner image in an AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445639/how-to-implement-a-jquery-spinner-image-in-an-ajax-request)

Comment: It didn't work it is a normal function, not an ajax but inside it calls multiple other ajax functions. When I add the spinner at the beginning of the code without hiding at the bottom then it displays but if i add hide function at the end of the function it never displays and the function is still working.

Comment: here is the js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/kdailearning/7defwaxp/5/ the code is too big to display here. I added a comment to display the div or any image but since the function is async and it is called multiple times. It executes everything and the working image doesn't display

Answer (score 0):

First download a spinner gif

Then, at the beginning of the function put this code:

$('#your-result-container').append('')

When your function ends

$('#your-result-container').empty();
${'#your-result-container').append('Success!');