# Rails 3: How to get javascript to run after link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my view I have a link_to for downloading an excel file:

```
<%= link_to 'Download Excel', url_for( :controller => "my_controller", :action => "file", :format => 'xlsx', :params => params ) %>
```

The controller uses axlsx to render the file like:

```
  format.xlsx {
    render xlsx: 'file', filename: 'filename', disposition: 'inline'
  }
```

Now it can take a bit of time to generate and return that file, so I'd like to give the user an indication that the site's working.

I have a hidden div in the view code:

```
<div id="loader"><img src="/assets/loading.gif" ></div>
```

When someone clicks on the link, I can show the div with this jQuery:

```
$('#excel_export').click(function() { 
  $("#loader").show();
});
```

My question is: how can I `.hide()` that div when the file download starts?  Maybe an ajax callback of some sort?

Comment: You might be able to repurpose [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4168965/382982).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this may help you. I found this code helpful to show spinner while an ajax request is performed.

```
$(document)
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $("#loader").show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
    });
```

You can get more samples from the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68503/2533958).

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout() function by checking general time taken for download to start

Like this

```
$('#excel_export').click(function() { 
  $("#loader").show();
  setTimeout($("#loader").hide();, 1000);
});
```

So it will be automatically close after 1000ms

Comment: Thanks, but the report won't necessarily take exactly one second to process.

Comment: This must be general execution time... you can use 5 seconds or 10 seconds... whatever you want