# Add Loading Spinner to JQuery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

could anyone suggest a way to add a spinner image to a jQuery Accordion as the accordion loads. I have tried a similar thing to how a spinner image could be added to a jQuery ui tab as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery%22here%22) - replacing tabs with accordion, but that hasn't worked.

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
  // loading spinner
  beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
 ui.newPanel.html('<img src="loading.gif" width="24" height="24" style="vertical-align:middle;"> Loading...');
}
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: "but that hasn't worked" Which means???

Comment: @A.Wolff - I just edited my original post to show what I mean. The loading spinner isn't being working.

Comment: Where do you see a `beforeLoad` method for jQuery UI accordion? You should provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue. BTW, what's wrong with solution in link you provided?

Comment: Tbh there's no beforeLoad event in the jQuery ui API doc for accordion but after using beforeActivate and it breaking the accordion I decided to try the beforeLoad anyways.

Comment: `ui.panel` won't exist (when you're using `beforeActivate`). You have the option of `ui.newHeader`, `ui.newPanel`, `ui.oldHeader` or `ui.oldPanel`