# jquery mobile loader standalone

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, loading

I've used jQuery Mobile on a project before and really liked the loader widget used for transitioning between pages.

Now, a different project requires a loading spinner, but I'm using Bootstrap for the core UI layout/elements. Data is loaded initially using Firebase, and I'd like to be able to use the loading spinner from jQuery Mobile until that loading is completed. Is there an easy way to get this widget standalone from the jQuery Mobile and include it as a standalone widget?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something extra manually with any standalone widget.

The provided links maybe helpful for you:

[How to show spinner during ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery)

[Jquery mobile loader](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/loader/)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand when you say "You have to do something extra manually with any standalone widget." Are you saying that this has to be done manually - i.e. there's not an easy way to pick and choose widgets from jQuery Mobile? Also, thanks for the links, but I misspoke when I said I was using ajax requests, I'm actually using Firebase for initial loading of data and real-time updates - I'll update my question to reflect.

Comment: Extra means, something could be done not with a widget but with your code and perhaps some CSS styles to fit your need.

Comment: Understood @Sohail, but the question was specifically about the jQuery Mobile loader widget. It's visually pleasing and very easy to use.