# How to show a message "Sorry it is taking time to load" on ajax if call take longer time

Tags: jquery, ajax

Say suppose there is my ajax call which call my `PHP` function to get some result.

```
$('.ui-loader').show();
$.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL +'some_page.php',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        async:false,
        success: function (response) {

             // response will get my result from "somepage.php"
             $('.ui-loader').hide();

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert(jqXHR.status);
        }
    });
```

How can I show a another loader which is stating that `"Sorry it is taking time please wait"` when ajax response taking time to get the result?

I come across [**ajaxStart()**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [**ajaxStop()**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) but how can I use here? Can you guys please guide me to achieve this thing.

**Note :** `$('.ui-loader').show();` is a simple loader I want to hide this loader and show another which is stating "Sorry it is taking time please wait".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You could do that using `setTimeout` like:

```
var longWaitTimerId = setTimeout(function () {
    //took longer than 5 seconds
}, 5000);

$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function (response) {
        clearTimeout(longWaitTimerId);
        ...
    },
    error: ... same as above
});
```

Comment: `clearTimeout(longWaitTimerId);` what it will do can you please explain me in detail. When I should show my specific loader when it will take more than 5 sec

Comment: `setTimeout` basically queues a function to be executed in `x` milliseconds. `setTimeout` returns the timer id so that it can be cancelled using `clearTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function MakeAjaxCall(){
//timer to show another loader
var timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('.ui-loader').hide();
        $('.ui-AnotherLoader').show();
    }, 2000);
$('.ui-loader').show();
$.ajax({
    url: BASE_URL +'some_page.php',
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    async:false,
    success: function (response) {
          //clear the timer if ajax call take less time
          wiundow.clreatTimeout(timer);
         // response will get my result from "somepage.php"
         $('.ui-loader').hide();
         $('.ui-AnotherLoader').hide();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //alert(jqXHR.status);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: `wiundow.clreatTimeout(timer);` syntax error correct it to `window.clearTimeout(timer);`