# jQuery blockUI not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-blockui

I'm trying to use blockUI but although it passes over with no errors, it doesn't work

the code below is all within the $(document).ready() function

```
$("#btnSaveJob").click(function () {

    if ($("#frmJobDetails").valid()) {
        $("#frmJobDetails").submit();
    }

});

$("#frmJobDetails").submit(function (e) {

    $('#jobDetails').block({
        message: 'Saving, please wait...',
        centerX: true,
        centerY: true,
        css: {
            width: '600px',
            height: '300px',
            border: '3px solid #FF9900',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            color: '#fff',
            padding: '25px'
        }
    });

    submitNew('job');
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#jobDetails').unblock();
});
```

edit to add in the submitNew function

> ```
> function submitNew(submitType) {
>
>
> // various variables set here
>
>     if (submitType == 'job') {
>         PageMethods.SubmitJobForm(propID, dateReceived, 
> targetResponse, targetComplete, chargeable, jobTypeID, 
> jobTypeText, contractID, contractText, csJobTypeID, 
> csJobTypeText, priorityID, priorityText, status, notes, 
> fnsuccesscallbackJob, fnerrorcallback);
>     }
>     else if (submitType == 'instruction') {
>         PageMethods.SubmitInstruction(fnsuccesscallbackInstruction,
> fnerrorcallback);
>
>     }
>     else {
>
>     }
>
> }
> ```

have to add this bit in as editor complaining I've added too much code....

Comment: what happens when you submit?

Comment: @SaidKholov everything else works as it should - the submitNew function is called

Comment: `unblock()` should be executed when your request is finish and not on submit

Comment: @IrvinDominin div on my page e.g.            <div id="jobDetails">

Comment: @leddy can I see the submitNew function? Is an ajax call?

Comment: @DrKey do you mean from within the submitNew function?

Comment: Is the submitNew an asynchronous function? If so, block() works perfectly but is directly unblocked. You should wait for submitNew to complete before unblocking.

Comment: @leddy exactly, I guess you call async in your `submitNew()` function, so `unblock()` is executed just after your `block()`

Comment: @IrvinDominin I've added the submitNew function, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.66.0-2013.10.09/jquery.blockUI.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function() {

            $('#form').validate({
                errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
                    error.insertBefore(element); // <- the default
                },

                rules : {
                    username : {
                        required : true
                    },
                    password : {
                        required : true,
                    },
                },
                messages : {
                    username : {
                        required : " Username required."
                    },
                    password : {
                        required : " Password required."
                    },
                },

            });
            if($('#form').valid()){
                $.blockUI({ message: 'Just a moment...</h1>' });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the current way the code is executed in the order:

- block
- submit function, async I think
- unblock

so since the submit function is async the unblock is executed too early and not when the submit process completes.

Try to move the unblock function in the complete/done function of the ajax call.

Comment: I've moved the unblock to the end of the submitNew function and it's still not being called

Comment: Not at the end of the function INSIDE tha ajax call, probably called in the function SubmitJobForm or in an inner

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to include these libs

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- Optional-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70/jquery.blockUI.min.js"></script>
```

For Blocking add this line
$.blockUI({ message: ' loading...' });

for unblocking add $.unblockUI();

function test()
    {

```
var rndomness="?rnd="+new Date().getTime()
var URL="XYZ"+rndomness
var snowId=document.getElementById("snowId").value;
var message = { snowId:snowId };
$.blockUI({ message: '<img src="resources/images/loadingajax.gif" /> Loading...' });
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url : URL,
             data: JSON.stringify(message),
             contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
             cache: false,
             success: function(response){

                 dowhatever u want to do with response

                 $.unblockUI();      
                }

        });

}
```

It is important that you have $.unblokUI inside success block

Answer (score 1):

In my case when the ajax call is synchronous that doesn't work e.g

```
 asynch:false
```

will not work, i set asynch:true and BlockUI is working

Comment: Thanks! you saved me1

Answer (score 0):

In my case when the ajax call is synchronous that doesn't work too

so I set async: true in my ajax code block and BlockUI is working

```
 async: true
```