# Rails | add ajax loading icon to remote: true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a link with `remote: true` attribute. It goes to the function then the js.erb file. My question is how can I add loading icon rails way?

For instance, if I put ajax request it is easy;

```
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {//add icon here}
        success: function(data){
        },
        error: function() {
        }
      });
```

But when I work with remote: true with link or button where should I put the loading icon.

PS: I do not want to add smth like below to the dom.

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function(){$('#div-to-loading').prepend('.loading-icon')})
```

**EDIT**

Please read my question carefully. I know how to add loading icon with ajax call. I am asking how to do it with **rails way**. I have a link with `remore:true` option. It goes to controller action then rendering js file `myfunc.js.erb`.

Where should I put loading icon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ajaxStart to show loading spinner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199304/how-to-use-ajaxstart-to-show-loading-spinner) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191485/how-to-call-ajaxstart-on-specific-ajax-calls

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?