# How can I addClass / removeClass multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to display a loading icon via CSS on my page when a user sends data via ajax, and then remove this loading icon once the ajax call is complete.  The page successfully shows the icon once, but not again without a page refresh.  However, the ajax call is being completed successfully for multiple calls.  Here is my code:

Relevant Html:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Loading.css" type="text/css&quot; id="loading_gif"/>
</head>
...
...
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="button">Import</button>
...
...
<div class="modal"><!-- Placed at bottom of page --></div>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {                        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Submit")',
            data: { 
              //submit data via jQuery 
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $body.addClass("loading");                        
            },
            success: function (data) {                        
                //render a partialView                    
            },
            complete: function () {
                $body.removeClass("loading");
            }
        });                
    });
}(jQuery));
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba( 128, 128, 128, .5 ) url('../img/ajax-loader-bar.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

/* When the body has the loading class, we turn
the scrollbar off with overflow:hidden */
body.loading {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Anytime the body has the loading class, our
modal element will be visible */
body.loading .modal {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: `#button` is dynamically replaced? Is the ID unique? Try `$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {`

Comment: Your `$(document).ready()` setup is incorrect. You're **calling** the "ready" handler. Remove the `(jQuery)` from the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Global setup for ajax calls**

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2387709/3298029

Here is a fiddle where the loading class is added and removed:
http://jsfiddle.net/0fpdud5h/

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function() {
     body.addClass('loading');
  },
  complete: function(){
     body.removeClass('loading');
  },
  success: function() {}
});
```

It triggers multiple times on this fiddle.
Hope this gets you started.