# How to show a indicator when clicked on a Button in this case

Tags: javascript, jquery

On Click Of the Try Again Button , is it possible to show some processing happening on the device

[My jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5cNX/53/)

My code as below

```
$(document).on("click", ".getStarted", function(event) {
    // Simulating Net Connection here
    var a = 10;
    if (a == 10) {
        $('#mainlabel').delay(100).fadeIn(300);
        $('#nonetconnmain').popup({
            history : false
        }).popup('open');
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
$(document).on('click', '.nonetconnmainclose', function(event) {
    $('#nonetconnmain').popup('close');
    $(".getStarted").trigger("click");
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$(document).on("popupbeforeposition", "#nonetconnmain", function(event, ui) {
    $('#mainlabel').hide();
});
```

With my code , the functionality is working , but it seems that the application is not doing any action

So my question is it possible to show any indication (For example , delay , progressbar , anything )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here ya go

```js
$(document).on("click", ".getStarted", function(event) {

  $.mobile.loading("show", {
    text: "",
    textVisible: true,
    theme: "z",
    html: ""
  });

  // Simulating Net Connection here
  var a = 10;
  if (a == 10) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      $.mobile.loading("hide");
      $('#mainlabel').fadeIn(300);
    }, 1000);


    $('#nonetconnmain').popup({
      history: false
    }).popup('open');
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;

  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.nonetconnmainclose', function(event) {


  $('#nonetconnmain').popup('close');
  $(".getStarted").trigger("click");
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});

$(document).on("popupbeforeposition", "#nonetconnmain", function(event, ui) {
  $('#mainlabel').hide();
});
```

```css
.popup {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
}
.popup h6 {
  font-size: 1.5em !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div data-role="page">


  <div data-role="popup" id="nonetconnmain" data-dismissible="false" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
    <div class="popup_inner popup_sm">
      <div class="popup_content" style="text-align:center;">
        <p class="">Please check net connectivcty</p>
        <label id="mainlabel" style="margin:100px auto 60px auto;color:Red; line-height:40px;font-size:medium;display:none">Please check</label>
      </div>
      <div class="popup_footer nonetconnmainclose">
        <a class="">Try Again</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <button class="getStarted btn btn-a get_btn">Click Here</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small function (with time as parameter) and use jQuery `animate()` to create the process effect like below.

```
var updateProgress = function(t) {
$( "#p" ).css("width",0);
$( "#p" ).show();
$( "#p" ).animate({ "width": "100%" }, t , "linear", function() {
$(this).hide();
});
}
```

Do notice that the time that is chosen when calling `updateProgress()` is relevant with the delay and the fade in effect of the text message

```
updateProgress(3500);
$('#mainlabel').delay(3400).fadeIn(600);
```

Check it on the snippet below

```js
var updateProgress = function(t) {
$( "#p" ).css("width",0);
$( "#p" ).show();
$( "#p" ).animate({ "width": "100%" }, t , "linear", function() {
$(this).hide();
});
}

  $(document).on("click", ".getStarted", function(event) { 
  var a = 10;
  if(a==10)
  {
    updateProgress(3500);
    $('#mainlabel').delay(3400).fadeIn(600);
    $('#nonetconnmain').popup({history: false}).popup('open');
                            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return false;

  }
});
$(document).on('click', '.nonetconnmainclose', function(event) {
  $('#nonetconnmain').popup('close');
       $(".getStarted").trigger("click");
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
});

$(document).on("popupbeforeposition", "#nonetconnmain",function( event, ui ) {
         $('#mainlabel').hide();
    });
```

```css
.popup {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
}
.popup h6 {
    font-size: 1.5em !important;
}
#p {
  border:none;
  height:1em;
  background: #0063a6;
  width:0%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div data-role="page">
    
  
   <div data-role="popup" id="nonetconnmain" data-dismissible="false" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
            <div class="popup_inner popup_sm">
                <div class="popup_content" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p class="">Please check net connectivcty</p>
                     <div id="p"></div><br>
                     <label id="mainlabel" style="margin:100px auto 60px auto;color:Red; line-height:40px;font-size:medium;display:none">Please check </label> 
                </div>
                <div class="popup_footer nonetconnmainclose">
                        <a class="">Try Again</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  
  
<button class="getStarted btn btn-a get_btn">Click Here</button>  
    
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5cNX/67/)

Answer (score 0):

Probably when you click  on try again , you can have a setinterval triggered which can check for online connectivity and when found can close the popup and get started again, also when we do retries in the interval the progress can be shown as progressing dots..
Below is the code, i haven't tried to run the code, but it shows the idea

```
$(document).on('click', '.nonetconnmainclose', function(event) {
var msgUI = $("#mainlabel");
msgUI.data("previoustext",msgUI.html()).html("retrying...");
var progress = [];
var counter = 0 ,timeout = 5;
var clearIt = setInterval(function(){
    var online = navigator.onLine;
    progress.push(".");
    if(counter > timeout && !online){
        msgUI.html(msgUI.data("previoustext"));
        counter=0;
    }
    if(online){
        $('#nonetconnmain').popup('close');
        $(".getStarted").trigger("click");
        counter=0;
        clearInterval(clearIt);
    }
else{
    msgUI.html("retrying" + progress.join(""));
    counter++;
}

},1000);
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
event.preventDefault();
return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure,

try appending a loader `GIF` to one of the `div` and remember to remove the same when your process is finished.

Kindly refer to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68485/1305969)

And try appending this

```
$('#nonetconnmain').append('<center><img style="height: 50px; position:relative; top:100px;" src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/0.16.1/images/…; alt="loading..."></center>');
```

This will append a loader to your HTML to show some kind of processing.

Comment: i tried this is not working , could you please let me know how to do this ??

Comment: try appending this $('#nonetconnmain').append('<center><img style="height: 50px; position:relative; top:100px;" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/0.16.1/images/loader-large.gif" alt="loading..."></center>');                                                                                                  this will append a loader to your html to show some kind of processing

Comment: @PreethiJain: I included the comment of kshitij into the question.