# How to show progress bar till i get a 200 status code of my POST call

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have developed a web page using flask and HTML to send email, I need to show a progress bar unless I get a 200 status code for POST.

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)   for start and learn how to ask good questions and edit yours if you need more help

Answer (score 1):

Please go through this answer:
You can use ajax call as explained in this answer

[Please go through this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68503/4044988)