# Hide and show loading gif not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to display a loading gif before load and hide it after load. Right now I have this:

```
<div id="loading-image" style="display: none">
  <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span> 
</div>
```

```js
$("#82348").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "{{ url('search') }}",
    dataType: "json",
    data: form.serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#searchResults').empty(); $("#loading-image").show(); 
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#loading-image").hide();
      // rest of ajax
```

However this is not working. Nothing is happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your `.submit()` event even firing? You should probably check using `console.log()`

Comment: And from there check that the request you send is coming back with a success code.

Comment: The AJAX is working. I didn't include the whole code because it is big. My only problem is hiding and showing the div with loading animation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show loading spinner in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery)