# I want to hide parent name which does not have child categories - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, categories

i want modification in this code to hide parent name which does not have child category.

I have tried but didn't got anything related to this.

```
 <?php    
$parent_categories = get_categories($parent_args); 

foreach($parent_categories as $parent_category){ ?>
<?php //create main headings for other categories other than Uncategorized.
if($parent_category->name!="Uncategorized"){
    $category_label = "By ";
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<h5>'.$category_label.''.$parent_category->name.'</h5>';

    //fetch the parent category's id
    $firstchild_args['parent'] = $parent_category->term_id;
    $firstchild_categories = get_categories($firstchild_args);

    //fetch all the first level children categories
    //fetch all the first level children categories
        $limit=15; // Set Child limit here
        $counter=0; 

        foreach($firstchild_categories as $firstchild_category){
        if($counter<$limit){
        $output = "";
        $output = $output."<div class=\"checkboxes-group\">";
        $output = $output."    <input type=\"checkbox\"  value=".$firstchild_category->slug." class=\"js-filter-checkbox\" name=\"category[]\" id=".$firstchild_category->cat_ID.">
        <span style='font-size: 17px; color: #404040;'>".$firstchild_category->name;
        $output = $output."</div>"; 
        echo $output;  
        $output = $output."</form>"; 
                $counter++;
        }
        }

}
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before printing anything you should first fetch all child category, Then you cant check child item is empty or not with `empty` function and then `continue` the current loop to skip this category, So you can add `if(empty($firstchild_categories)) continue` and your could can be like this

```
<?php
$parent_categories = get_categories($parent_args);
$limit   = 15; // Set Child limit here
$counter = 0;

foreach ($parent_categories as $parent_category) {
 //create main headings for other categories other than Uncategorized.
    if ($parent_category->name != "Uncategorized") {


        //fetch the parent category's id
        $firstchild_args['parent'] = $parent_category->term_id;
        $firstchild_categories     = get_categories($firstchild_args);

        if( empty($firstchild_categories) )
           continue;

        if($counter > $limit)
           break;
        $counter++;
        $category_label = "By ";
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<h5>' . $category_label . '' . $parent_category->name . '</h5>';

        //fetch all the first level children categories
        //fetch all the first level children categories


        foreach ($firstchild_categories as $firstchild_category) {

                $output = "";
                $output = $output . "<div class=\"checkboxes-group\">";
                $output = $output . "    <input type=\"checkbox\"  value=" . $firstchild_category->slug . " class=\"js-filter-checkbox\" name=\"category[]\" id=" . $firstchild_category->cat_ID . ">
        <span style='font-size: 17px; color: #404040;'>" . $firstchild_category->name;
                $output = $output . "</div>";
                echo $output;
                $output = $output . "</form>";

        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this works like a charm!, i have one more question i also wanted to limit the number of categories to be displayed.. i just want to show 4 categories here, and if needed i can increase it as per my requirement...

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i put ajax loader icon when the chechbox gets clicked and till time when it loads i want to display one loader image.

Comment: @ShahnawazKhan You can use jquery for this, look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/68485/1827594

Comment: In this code all posts which are not published are too displaying i don't want unpublished posts to be displayed in this...